# Angular 1.5 component router

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I am dealing with angular 1.5.8 component router.
I have installed component router in my project via npm as described here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngComponentRouter

In my main app.js file

```
import angular from 'angular';
import '@angular/router/angular1/angular_1_router';

let app = angular.module('appName', [
    'ngComponentRouter'
]);
```

I have imported the router module.
I need to do this this way therefore I use browserify to bundle my app.

And problem appears after importing **angular_1_router** I am getting a lot of errors while boundling errors for example

> Cannot find module './lifecycle_annotations_impl' from
>   '/node_modules/@angular/router/angular1'

I found out that router module requires a lot of modules that does not exist.

Here is angular_1_router.js code http://pastebin.com/6icdMTvS
For example in line 884

```
var lifecycle_annotations_impl_1 = require('./lifecycle_annotations_impl');
```

Do you have any idea where I can find these modules or any other solution for the problem?

Comment: Isn't it `ngComponentRouter` is deprecated?